# Can I force anonymous default export?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, eslint-plugin-import

If you have a file named same as default export, why do you need to name this export? I am not `DRY` there.

We have a [rule to prevent the anonymous default export](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md), but how can I do the opposite and force an error when somebody is *not* using an anonymous export?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Are you asking how to disable that eslint rule? Or are you asking why that rule exists? In general, there exists an eslint for every thing anyone might complain about, ever. You don't have to abide by all those rules if it's not right for your codebase.

Comment: @AlexWayne, edited my question a bit, thanks, I need to force an error if somebody is not using anonymous default export

Answer (score 5):

> If you have a file named same as default export, why do you need to name this export?

You don't.  That's why you are linking to a linter rule - it's not required, but considered "best practice" by some, because

> Ensuring that default exports are named helps improve the grepability of the codebase by encouraging the re-use of the same identifier for the module's default export at its declaration site and at its import sites.

Basically, people think that if you have

```
export default () => { console.log('Hello'); }
```

people are more likely to do

```
import logHello from 'sayHello'; // file one
import greeting from 'sayHello'; // file two
import sayHello from 'sayHello'; // file three
```

but that if you do

```
const sayHello = () => {
    console.log('Hello');
}
export default sayHello
```

people will more consistently do

```
import sayHello from 'sayHello';
```

which makes the code easier to read, because the same function is called the same thing no matter where you import it from.

When you ask

> how can I force it?

I am *assuming* you mean how can you force the linter to accept your anonymous default export?  You would either need to inline disable the rule:

```
/* eslint import/no-anonymous-default-export: [2, {"allowArrowFunction": true}] */
export default () => {}
```

or update your eslint config to accept it in general.

Comment: Thanks, this you gave a good explanation, but my team and I are decided to use the anonymous exports, so I need to force an error if somebody is not using anonymous default export for class or function

Comment: I.e. you want a linter rule that does the opposite of what the one that you linked does, is that right?

Comment: @CherryDT, yup, I need the opposite rule

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to have an anonymous default export even though your linter prevents it, [you can use comments to disable eslint rules](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#disabling-rules). So, for your scenario, `// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export` should work. Or you can modify the [eslint config](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#using-configuration-files-1) if you want to disable that rule everywhere.

But you should read the justification for naming default exports:

> Ensuring that default exports are named helps improve the grepability of the codebase by encouraging the re-use of the same identifier for the module's default export at its declaration site and at its import sites.

For exported classes in particular, another thing to consider is that naming the exported class will set its `constructor.name`, which can be useful.

```js
const bar = class Foo {};
(new bar()).constructor.name; // 'Foo'
```

Comment: Thanks for `constructor.name`, I didn't know about this, we're using `export default function () {...}` mostly, so I need to force an error if someone tries to do `export default function Do() {...}`